# Azure WebJob Multiple executables

Tags: azure, exe, azure-webjobs

I am creating a WebJob (console executable). This .exe invokes one of the configured plug-ins which are in the form of executable again.
So, when I deploy a WebJob, it contains 3 or more executable. Is there a way to execute only one .exe as a WebJob and block the execution of other .exe ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to also include a `run.cmd` file at the root of your WebJobs files, and have it just be a one-liner that runs whichever exe you want. Once you do that, only this batch file will be executed, giving you precise control over exactly what you want to run.

You'll find more details [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-jobs).